# In which file should I initialize objects in Express.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to Node.js and Express.

I want to use [log4js](https://github.com/nomiddlename/log4js-node) but not certain about in which file I should configure my logger.

Is there a conventional file for the initialization? If not, where should I create a new configuration file?

Thanks :)

## Answer (based on @jfriend00 answer)

In `logger.js`

```
'use strict';

var log4js = require('log4js');

log4js.configure({
  "appenders": [...]
});

var logger = log4js.getLogger("structuredLogger");

module.exports = logger
```

In `client.js`

```
var logger = require('../../../../../config/logger.js');
logger.info('My message');
```

This module will allow me to:

- Easily configure the the log4js
- Easily replace the log4js with another package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One common option for a module that needs to get initialized once is to create your own container module that does the initialization.  Then, every other module that wants to use the logging can just load your container module and, if not already initialized, your container module will initialize the logging.

```
// mylog.js

// initialization code will only be called the first time the module is loaded
// after that, the module is cached by the `require()` infrastructure
var log4js = require('log4js');
log4js.configure({
  appenders: [
    { type: 'console' },
    { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/cheese.log', category: 'cheese' }
  ]
});

module.exports = log4js;
```

Then, every module that wishes to use the common configuration logging can just do this near the top of the module:

```
var log4js = require('./mylog.js');
```